# Word(s) for close family friends

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There may not be anything better than in my title, but I have an idea I'm missing something. Is there a good way of expressing close friends of a family.  The original and closest friendship may be with a generation now passed on, but a family-like relationship still exists.

The best I can come up with is honorary aunt/uncle/grandparent, but that's a little specific.

Comment: Why not the selfsame '(close) family friend' you used in the title?

Comment: You don't find _intimates_ quite fit the task?

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան that might have to do, I just felt like there might be something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ***cherished*** friends, since you hold them dear and have a fond affection for them?

EDIT: Following @TrevorD's comment below I propose that the most suitable idiom is - *like one of the family.*

Comment: That doesn't convey the notion of a *family* friend.

Answer (score 1):

There are terms like *loved ones* and *intimates*, but their use depends on the nature of the relationships being described.

Comment: And they don't convey the notion of *family* friends.

Answer (score 0):

Kin, clan, tribe could be used for blood relatives or for traceable roots; progeny (as with gene relations).
or perhaps kinship, soul-tribe or mate for friends who are bonded as, or are considered to be close... also certain areas of the world use "Mate"(not gender specific) or cousin to describe close friends.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).